# magento 2 get first level category from current catgeory ID in controller

Tags: category, magento2.3, controllers, sub-categories

I am trying to get first level category from current category ID in my controller . 
For example- I have

> - Maincategory
>
>   - SubCategory1
>
>     - SubCategory2
>
>       - SubChild1
>       - SubChild2.

I want to access Maincategory in my controller whether my current catgeory id is SubChild1 or it's SubCategory1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with add below code in your controller to get using your category id to get all parent categories..

```
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$parentCategories = $category->getParentCategories();
```